# If the distance between galaxies is increasing and the speed of light is constant will the most of the light from the universe ever reach us?

Tags: light, distances, expansion, speed

Will the light from other galaxies ever reach us if the universe is expanding?

Comment: Thanks for the edit, there's nothing wrong with clearly written question being short!

Comment: You may enjoy the Scientific American article by Davis & Lineweaver about expansion: https://people.smp.uq.edu.au/TamaraDavis/papers/SciAm_BigBang.pdf For more details, see their classic paper, [Expanding Confusion: common misconceptions of cosmological horizons and the superluminal expansion of the Universe](https://arxiv.org/abs/astro-ph/0310808).

Comment: Related question: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/129980/expansion-of-the-universe-will-light-from-some-galaxies-never-reach-us

Comment: Related: https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/a/1615/893